# Redirect a Named Pipe directly to stdout in PHP

Tags: php, pipe, ipc

I want to redirect the content of a named pipe ([FIFO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)) to stdout while writing to an other named pipe.

Following scenario in a server side PHP script:

```
//Write some Text to STDOUT by PHP
echo "Pre Text";  
//Redirect the  Content to stdout ...
$handle = NON_BLOCKING_REDIRECT('/run/pipeXYZ',STDOUT); 

//..while writing to an other name pipe
file_put_contents('/run/otherPipe','MyCommand');  

WAIT_UNTIL_FINISHED($handle);

//Write again some Text to STDOUT by PHP
echo "Post Text";
```

Is this possible? What would be the stuff for for `NON_BLOCKING_REDIRECT, WAIT_UNTIL_FINISHED`?

Comment: So, you want to write to a socket while reading an other socket in parallel?
"named pipe" means unix socket?

Comment: @RiWe See my Edit about the FIFO